# Unable to get value of the property 'renderer': object is null or undefined: Jqplot

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqplot

I am using jqplot for plotting piechart,bar and line chart. It is work fine in IE9>=. But it is not working in IE8. It gives me above error when I am using both piechart and bar chart. and it is showing error at piechart plugin at e.jqplot.PieRenderer'. After blocking this plugin bar chart works fine but not piecharts. Below is my code. Please suggest on this.

```
var optionsObj = {
            title: 'Item wise stock',
            animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: dates,
                    label: 'Item'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickOptions: { showMark: true, formatString: "%d" },
                    padMin: 0,
                    label: 'Stock',
                    angle: -30,
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                    labelOptions: { fontSize: '11px' }
                }
            },

            grid: {
                drawGridLines: true,        // wether to draw lines across the grid or not.
                gridLineColor: '#cccccc',    // *Color of the grid lines.
                background: '#e6e6e6',      // CSS color spec for background color of grid.
                borderColor: '#999999',     // CSS color spec for border around grid.
                borderWidth: 2.0,           // pixel width of border around grid.
                shadow: true,               // draw a shadow for grid.
                shadowAngle: 45,            // angle of the shadow.  Clockwise from x axis.
                shadowOffset: 1.5,          // offset from the line of the shadow.
                shadowWidth: 3,             // width of the stroke for the shadow.
                shadowDepth: 3,             // Number of strokes to make when drawing shadow.
                // Each stroke offset by shadowOffset from the last.
                shadowAlpha: 0.07,           // Opacity of the shadow
                renderer: $.jqplot.CanvasGridRenderer,  // renderer to use to draw the grid.
                rendererOptions: {}         // options to pass to the renderer.  Note, the default
                // CanvasGridRenderer takes no additional options.
            },

            series: [
                { label: 'Bar', renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer },
                { label: 'Line', renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer, color: '#ef8c08' },
                ],

            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 'ne'
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                shadow: false,
                rendererOptions: {
                    barPadding: 0,
                    barMargin: 10,
                    barWidth: 25,
                    highlightMouseDown: true
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 7.5,
                tooltipContentEditor: function (str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, jqPlot) {

                    return '<table class="jqplot-highlighter"><tr><td>Item:</td><td>' + data[pointIndex][0].toString() + '</td></tr>  \
                     <tr><td>Stock:</td><td>' + data[pointIndex][1].toString() + '</td></tr></table>'

                }

            }
        };

        var plot2 = $.jqplot(location, values, optionsObj);
```

Comment: just off top of my head, why are u using bar and pie together. i am not able to understand what kind of output do u expect from it?

Comment: These are separate graphs on one page.

Comment: can you share jsfiddle eaxple as what is the output

Answer (score 1):

Include this tag in your html page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="excanvas.js"></script>
```

IE8 requires excanvas library to create canvas elements because IE8 doen't support canvas elements.

You can download the js file from here: [Excanvas library](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)

Comment: make sure this is the first file that gets included. Your error is because of this only. I am 100% sure because i tested your code.